# ValueError: Shapes () and (150, 5) are incompatible Tenosrflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So I am training a image classification model and this error appears. There does not seem any answer to this error. Can someone please explain me what is wrong with my code. I am using tf.data. Is there any problems with the labels.What can i do to solve this issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

import cv2
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Activation, Conv1D, MaxPool1D

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Input, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
training_folder = r"F:\Pycharm_projects\Kaggle Cassava\data\train_images"
samples_df = pd.read_csv(r"F:\Pycharm_projects\Kaggle Cassava\data\train.csv")
samples_df = shuffle(samples_df, random_state=42)
samples_df["label"] = samples_df["label"].astype("str")
samples_df.head()
temp_labels = {}
imgg = []
lab = []
for i in range(len(samples_df)):
    image_name = samples_df.iloc[i, 0]
    image_label = samples_df.iloc[i, 1]
    la = {image_name: image_label}
    temp_labels.update(la)
print(len(temp_labels))
for im in tqdm(os.listdir(training_folder)):
    path = os.path.join(training_folder, im)
    label = temp_labels.get(im)
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    img = tf.image.random_crop(img, size=(150, 150, 3))
    imgg.append(img)
    lab.append(label)

lables = np.array(lab).astype(np.float32)
img = np.array(imgg).astype(np.float32)
train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img, lables)).shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
print(tf.data.Dataset.cardinality(train))
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(5, activation="sigmoid"))

tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.0001, )
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss="categorical_crossentropy"
              ,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, epochs=1)
```

What can I do to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you feed images, you should use `Conv2D` instead of `Conv1D`. ([see doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D))

Then, Add this :

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(150,150,3)))
```

between this two layers :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(150,50)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, strides=(1,1), activation="relu"))
```

Also change the model.fit

```
model.fit(images,labels, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, epochs=1)
```

Comment: i am getting this ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_4 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 5)

Comment: I don't know what you're feeding to your network, what's the shape of your images ?

Comment: 150,150,3 see this     img = tf.image.random_crop(img, size=(150, 150, 3))

Comment: getting this ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 150, 150). Should i add something to the image size

Comment: after the edit getting this error ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 150, 150)

Comment: try this model.fit(img, lables, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, epochs=1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225238/discussion-between-mithil-salunkhe-and-bdouchet).

Answer (score 0):

at first, change your last layer activation function. "sigmoid" activation used for binary classification. It seems you have 5 class not 2. so change "sigmoid" to "softmax" and try again.

Comment: still getting the ```     ValueError: Shapes () and (150, 5) are incompatible
```